# Devider widget vs custom paint to draw a simple line, 1000 lines, will there be any performance difference for the app?

Tags: flutter

In a hypothetical situation, say I have a page which loads shopping items which has a simple horizontal `Line` in each widget. Say there will be 1000 items, that is `1000 lines` are shown to the client. Can there be any `significant performance difference` if I use to `draw a line using` custom paint`than using the`devider `widget`? I find it so easy to use custom paint and customize it and `I prefer to use custom paint`, but I feel like to draw a simple line I spend a lot of processing power which might slow down the app? or the difference is insignificant even for 1000 lines displayed? I will use the app in both ios and android platforms.

Comment: first of all not 1000 - if you use `ListView.builder` it will be 10 or so (number of visible items) or 2 if you use `PageView.builder` - also, if you use `Divider`, under the hood it uses [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/18116933e7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/divider.dart#L207) so you can compare what is more complex

Comment: @pskink thanks a lot for shedding some light :)